# Display a div width 100% with margins

Tags: html, css

I want to display an expandable `div` (`width: 100%`) with margins...

```css
#page {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#margin {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="margin">
    "some content here"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't put margin:10px and width:100% on the same level. 
create child div to put width:100%, and You can keep the margin on the parent.

Comment: While the answers seem to work, it would be nice to know why the code in the question doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following CSS to achieve the desired result:

```
#page {
   background: red;
   overflow: auto;
}

#margin {
   background: green;
   height: 280px;
   margin: 10px
}
```

Comment: Completely removing the width doesn't seem like the appropriate way to solve the problem of combining margin and width functionality.

Answer (score 101):

You can use `calc()` css function ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)).

```
#page {
  background: red;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#margin {
  background: green;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}​
```

Alternatively, try using padding instead of margin and `box-sizing: border-box` ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)):

```
#page {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#margin {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: The best solution is to use `calc()` in modern browsers, and JS code + Modernizr for older browser which doesn't support `calc()`.

Comment: Css function ? thats sound great... but i use chrome and chrome tell me "invalid property value"... but why ?

Comment: You have to use `calc(100% - 10px)` (space between number and minus). Also for chrome and safari use `-webkit` prefix, `-moz` for FF and `-o` for Opera!

Comment: If you want to be cross-browser compatible, this probably is not the best approach. Since often users don't have to latest and greatest browser...

Comment: Why isn't this `calc(100% - 20px)`? `10px` would only be one side of the margin and would only reduce the width by half the required distance to fit. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: There is a new CSS value for `width` that can allow you to automatically use a full width including margins. It looks like `width: stretch` but it's still prefixed in most browsers. In Chrome (et al) it's `-webkit-fill-available`, in Firefox it's `-moz-available`. [caniuse link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width)

Answer (score 18):

Sometimes it's better to do the opposite and give the parent `div` padding instead:

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AVSnd/8/)**

What I did was change the CSS of `#page` to:

```
#page {
    padding: 3%;
    width: 94%; /* 94% + 3% +3% = 100% */

    /* keep the rest of your css */
    /* ... */
}
```

Then delete the `margin` from `#margin`

Note: this also adds 3% to the top and bottom (so 6% to the height) which makes it a little taller than 300px - so if you need exactly 300px, you could do something like `padding:10px 3%;` and change the `height:280px;` to add up to 300px again.

Comment: This is the right approach for doing calculations with CSS for now. This illustrates the basic principle that you end up with a `div` structure that mimic the parse tree of the expression you want to evaluate.

Answer (score 13):

The correct way to achieve this by standard is:

```
#margin {
   background: green;
   height: 280px;
   margin: 10px;
   width: auto;
   display: block;
}
```

Comment: +1 As `width: auto` worked like a charm compared to `width: 100%`. Having googled the difference I'm not sure why anybody would use 100%. If they know what they're doing. Which I certainly don't.

Comment: There is no "correct" way, and this question goes beyond elements which are `display:block` by default (like tables for example), therefor this solution is lacking.

Comment: Well, `width: auto;` is the default value for that property. So adding it is redundant, in my opinion. Not that the answer is not right, just don't add css for a property if you're going to set it to its default value.

Answer (score 4):

**For LESS users only:**

Using the nice solution of Vukašin Manojlović doesn't work out of the box because LESS executes + or - operations during the LESS compilation. 
One solution is to escape LESS so that it doesn't execute the operation.

[Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc)

```
@someMarginVariable = 15px;

margin: @someMarginVariable;
width: calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -moz-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -o-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
```

or can use a mixin like:

```
.fullWidthMinusMarginPaddingMixin(@marginSize,@paddingSize) {
  @minusValue: (@marginSize+@paddingSize)*2;
  padding: @paddingSize;
  margin: @marginSize;
  width: calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
  width: -moz-calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
  width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
  width: -o-calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try to use padding with box-sizing instead, on #page element

```
#page {
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
#margin {
    background: green;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You've replaced margin on the inner element with padding on the outer element, so of course it works. But the question is about how to combine `width 100%` with `margin`. Simply adding `border-box` does not solve the problem.