# Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()

Tags: css, less, css-calc

Right Now I'm trying to do this in CSS3 in my LESS code:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

However, when LESS compiles it is outputting this:

```
width: calc(-100%);
```

Is there a way to tell LESS not to compile it in that manner and to output it normally?

Comment: I thought my solution was a pretty ugly hack already, but the most upvoted dupe uses virtually the same hack as mine so I guess there are not many other (cleaner) ways. `:P`

Comment: Note that Less no longer collapses these calculations within `calc()` regardless of the `math` setting.

Answer (score 831, accepted):

Using an [**escaped string**](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-Escaping) (a.k.a. escaped value):

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 200px)";
```

---

Also, in case you need to mix Less math with escaped strings:

```
width: calc(~"100% - 15rem +" (10px+5px) ~"+ 2em");
```

Compiles to:

```
width: calc(100% - 15rem + 15px + 2em);
```

This works as Less concatenates values (the escaped strings and math result) with a space by default.

Comment: Note that the `~"value"` syntax has been replaced with the `e("value")` function. See here: http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e

Comment: @chharvey are you sure? The [`~""` documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-escaping) has no deprecation notice. In fact, if I'm reading the [`e()` function docs](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) correctly, it is the `e` function that has been replaced with `~""`. This [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8331285) reaffirms this point.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes you're right. I misread the alert in the `e()` docs. the `~''` syntax seems to be newer.

Comment: Hi. A Less.js language designer here. What would you think about a tweak to language syntax to interpret the entire statement as a string? As in:
`width~: calc(100% - 200px);`
equivalent to:
`width: ~"calc(100% - 200px)";`

Comment: @MatthewDean That looks like an improvement, in my opinion. Though, I usually dislike having multiple ways to write the same thing—it is one more  (unnecessary) choice you have to make, one more thing learners have to keep in mind, and leads to coding style discussions. Of course, as a language designer you most surely already know all these drawbacks, so I'd leave it to your team to discuss whether this syntax sugaring is worth it. And, to be honest, I've had little use for calc/escaped strings lately as I can usually solve the problem in a simpler and more robust way using Flexbox layout.

Answer (score 64):

Apart from using an escaped value as described in [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904128/1331430), it is also possible to fix this issue by enabling the [Strict Math](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-strict-math) setting.

With strict math on, only maths that are inside unnecessary parentheses will be processed, so your code:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
```

Would work as expected with the strict math option enabled.

**However**, note that Strict Math is applied globally, not only inside `calc()`. That means, if you have:

```
font-size: 12px + 2px;
```

The math will no longer be processed by Less -- it will output `font-size: 12px + 2px` which is, obviously, invalid CSS. You'd have to wrap all maths that should be processed by Less in (previously unnecessary) parentheses:

```
font-size: (12px + 2px);
```

Strict Math is a nice option to consider when starting a new project, otherwise you'd possibly have to rewrite a good part of the code base. For the most common use cases, the escaped string approach described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17904128/1331430) is more suitable.

Comment: To enable strict math in for example gulp, pass the following option: `less({strictMath: true})`

Answer (score 24):

Here's a cross-browser less mixin for using CSS's `calc` with any property:

```
.calc(@prop; @val) {
  @{prop}: calc(~'@{val}');
  @{prop}: -moz-calc(~'@{val}');
  @{prop}: -webkit-calc(~'@{val}');
  @{prop}: -o-calc(~'@{val}');
}
```

Example usage:

```
.calc(width; "100% - 200px");
```

And the CSS that's output:

```
width: calc(100% - 200px);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
width: -o-calc(100% - 200px);
```

A codepen of this example: http://codepen.io/patrickberkeley/pen/zobdp

Comment: throws `ParseError: Syntax Error on line 2`

Comment: @TomRoggero what version of less are you running? What's the rest of your environment? I've updated the original answer to include a working example.

Comment: I would advise against this. It's better to keep your CSS pure, and then use something like Autoprefixer to add prefix not just to `calc` but to any other attribute one might be using.

Comment: this is awesome Patrick, I've issued a PR against LESS-Prefixer for inclusion

Answer (score 15):

Example for escaped string with variable:

```
@some-variable-height: 10px;

...

div {
    height: ~"calc(100vh - "@some-variable-height~")";
}
```

compiles to

```
div {
    height: calc(100vh - 10px );
}
```

Comment: ...while SCSS Syntax would be something like
height: calc(100vh - #{$some-variable-height})

Answer (score 6):

The solutions of Fabricio works just fine.

A very common usecase of calc is add 100% width and adding some margin around the element.

One can do so with:

```
@someMarginVariable: 15px;

margin: @someMarginVariable;
width: calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -moz-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
width: -o-calc(~"100% - "@someMarginVariable*2);
```

Or can use a mixin like:

```
.fullWidthMinusMarginPaddingMixin(@marginSize,@paddingSize) {
  @minusValue: (@marginSize+@paddingSize)*2;
  padding: @paddingSize;
  margin: @marginSize;
  width: calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
  width: -moz-calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
  width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
  width: -o-calc(~"100% - "@minusValue);
}
```

Comment: Your example of passing a variable into the calc was super helpful. The exact follow-on question I had after reading the above accepted answer. 

Comment: np however I think the example of patrickberkeley is better than mine ;)

Comment: What is the sense to mix calc with margin?

Comment: @Dmitry why not? how do you take 100%-20px of the width of a container without that kind of trick, and if you can't use flexbox grow?