# deactivate less temporarily - having a less-free expression

Tags: css, less

less is really helpful for clean css. but now I have problem with it

I want to center a div box and gave it the following style:

```
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 100px);
  left: calc(50% - 200px);
}
```

but now less thinks it should calculate 50% minus 100px, can't do that and write instead: `left: calc(-50%)` (50-100 = -50)

Is there a way to tell less that it should let this particular code snippet as it is?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bless%5d%20calc

Comment: Are you using the original JS-based less parser, or one of a library for some other language like Ruby or PHP?

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks a lot! question is answered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc/17904128#17904128)

You can use an escaped value:

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 200px)";
```

---

Also, in case you need to mix Less math with escaped values:

```
width: calc(~"100% - 15rem +" (10px+5px) ~"+ 2em");
```

Compiles to:

```
width: calc(100% - 15rem + 15px + 2em);
```

This works as Less concatenates values (the escaped values and math result) with a space by default.