# Using CSS3 calc() function

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the `calc()` function, but it return the wrong value.

I'm using this:

```
height: calc(100% - 45px);  
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 45px);  
height: -moz-calc(100% - 45px);
```

..but it sets the **height** to **55%**. Why? What am I doing wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/L7x9j/

Comment: If you have previously set the height to 55%, it could be that your stylesheet is being cached locally. Open the webpage in incognito, or even better clear your browser's cache to rule this out.

Comment: I think your element should be floated first eigher to right or left.

Comment: Though I don't know the answer to your question, I do know that `height: -webkit-height: calc(...);` is not valid CSS. I think you want `height: -webkit-calc(...);`.

Comment: @Jordan is right and the same goes for the -moz prefix too, it should be `height: -moz-calc(...);`. That being said, I doubt this is the problem as modern browsers support this rule without the vendor prefixes.

Comment: In my code it's just like @Jordan pointed... SOrry, my bad! I just wrote wrong here. =s

Comment: In which browser (and version) do you get the wrong result? And how did you check that the resulting height is `55%`?

Comment: Put your example in a jsfiddle to see the problem. With `height` and % values it's often a problem with the parent element.

Comment: I updated my question with the jsfiddle example.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro In the example, you explicityly set `calc(55%)`. Did you add the wrong jsFiddle?

Comment: @JoshCrozier & t.niese. Geee, Let me explain... I'm using .Less to write my CSS, in my less document I wrote calc(100% - 45px) but in my .css file it's Calc(55%), may this be the cause of the error ?

Comment: Well `calc(55%)` is not the same as `calc(100% - 45px)` so yes, _LESS_ is doing something the wrong way (without rendering the page you never can calculate the final result of `%-px`) or you did not carefully read the documentation if and where it is ok to write calculations in the less file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Less Aggressive Compilation with CSS3 calc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `calc()`, it works. You just need to set a height of `100%` for the `body`/`html` elements in order for it to work as desired.

Compare [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/RTEJe/show/) (without `html, body { height:100%; }`) to this [**fixed example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EZH4X/show/).

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
#mid-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 50px);
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 50px);
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Additionally, it's worth noting that the `header` is `50px`, not `45px`. I also added `box-sizing:border-box` in order to include borders/padding in the element's box model calculations.

You may notice that there is space at the bottom if the screen size is less than `~700px`. That's because of the following:

```
#mid-content h1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    font-size: 58px;
    line-height: 1em;
    font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif;
    margin: 100px auto 70px auto;
    color: white;
}
```

Removal of the `height`/`margin` fixes it. [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/vvRMP/)

Comment: I think the problem is with the .less file, isn't it? Or your answer is the reason to .less compiler set the calc(55%) ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro See the updated answer. Is that what you were after?

Comment: @JoshCrozier the problem is that the OP uses _LESS_ to create the final css file and that _LESS_  already produces the incorrect `calc(55%)`.

Comment: @t.niese Right, but even if LESS produced the correct result, `calc(100% - 50px)`, it still wouldn't work as expected. Compare those examples I posted.

Comment: @t.niese is right. The .LESS is creating this Calc(55%). Guess i'll get back to pure .css file. =s

Comment: The LESS problem is solvable and has been answered several times before, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972084/less-aggressive-compilation-with-css3-calc

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro No, you can still use LESS. Use `height: ~"calc(100% - 50px)";` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc

Answer (score 10):

I had a same problem, `Calc()` was calculating wrong %age.

Keep strict math set to `on`.

```
height: ~"calc(100% - 50px)";
```

This fixed the issue for me.