# Unexpected effects of LESS calc() function

Tags: html, css, less

This code:

`index.htm.twig`

```
<div id="myBar">Hello</div>
<div id="myDiv">{VERY_LONG_LOREM_IPSUM}</div>
```

pure `style.css`

```
#myBar {
    height: 40px;
}
#myDiv {
    height: calc(100% - 40px); // document height - #myBar height
}
```

Everything is OK here.

But when I change pure style.css to style.less:

`style.less`

```
#myBar {
    height: 40px;
}
#myDiv {
    height: calc(100% - 40px); // document height - #myBar height
}
```

The function `calc(100% - 40px);` is compiled to `calc(60%);` in `style.css`.
I expected the same value like in pure `style.css` file.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm assuming your css doesn't actually use equal signs but properly uses `:`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [**LESS Documentation - String Functions - Escaping**](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e)
>
> CSS escaping, replaced with `~"value"` syntax.

When you're using LESS, you need to escape it, otherwise the numbers will be evaluated, as you are seeing. In this case, you would use `calc(~"100% - 40px")`:

```
#myDiv {
    height: calc(~"100% - 40px");
}
```