# calc(xx% - yypx) isn't working, and I didn't forget the spaces

Tags: css

I have the following css:

```
#elementid {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 30px);
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}
```

The element renders narrower than expected . In Chrome, if I inspect the element, it shows:

```
width: -webkit-calc(70%);
width: -moz-calc(70%);
width: -o-calc(70%);
width: calc(70%);
```

So it's apparently interpreted the 'px' as % instead.

But if I enter the exact same CSS inline on the element, in Chrome dev tools:

```
width: calc(100% - 30px);
```

... then it renders as I expect.

As you can see I added spaces around the operator properly, so that's not it.

Why would the browser interpret it as "calc(70%)" when rendering the page, but not when I change the CSS inline using dev tools?

Comment: The real question is why Chrome is bothering with all those values in the first place. I would expect it to ignore the -moz- and -o- values at least... but then again, this *is* Chrome we're talking about.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/voprm19w/).

Comment: Are you using pure css? because in less you have to escape the `calc` like this: `~'calc(100% - 30px)'`

Comment: I have a feeling this is Less problem, not CSS.

Comment: Watch out for the prefix bandit: `-o-calc` does not exist.

Comment: Chrome struck through the first 3 and only paid attention to the plain "calc" attribute
@Yandy_Viera: Success! I am using LESS, and that did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some browsers accept additional proprietary non-standard non-css
> syntax on top of the usual css. Less is build on top of standard css
> and therefore may not recognize it. You may also need to put an
> otherwise non-parseable value inside a variable and use it to
> dynamically build selector or other css part during compilation time.
>
> Escaping allows you to use any arbitrary string as property or
> variable value. It can be used also to dynamically build selectors,
> but that feature is deprecated and replaced by different more powerful
> option.
>
> Use either ~"whatever" or ~'whatever' syntax to escape property
> values. Anything between quotes is used as is with almost no changes.
> The "as is" rule has one exception: string interpolation works with
> the usual @{variableName} syntax.

So would be `width: ~'calc(100% - 30px)';`

Otherwise LESS will do the math inside the parenthesis first. There is a "Strict Math" setting for LESS to work around this.

Check this amazing answer for more information [Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc)