# The calc() returns percentage, not pixels?

Tags: css, less, calc

This is my code:

```
width: -moz-calc(100% - 30px);
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 30px);
width: calc(100% - 30px);
```

I want the width to be 100% and subtract 30px. However Chromes inspect element calculate this to be 70%
I tried to search for this problem, but everbody said that the way i write it, is the way it have to be written.
This is what Chrome returns:

```
width: -moz-calc(70%); --> line-through
width: -webkit-calc(70%); --> line-through
width: calc(70%);
```

I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: You are mixing pixels and percentage, so the software is confused. It could have returned an "Undefined" answer.

Comment: How should this look then?

Comment: Did you use pre-processor css like less or sass since they need to be escaped when used with calc() method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc

Comment: What is the parent element's width? What is the 100% relative to?

Comment: Sorry yes i use LESS. And the parent is 100% in width to. And that parent is 100% in width, which is the full screen width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out!
Thanks to Danny Pranoto it was because there was a different in the syntax when using LESS. Forgot to tell i use LESS. Sorry guys!

The answer and right syntax was this:

```
width: ~"calc(100% - 200px)";
```

Comment: Interesting... This one has fixed the issue. It's worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
width: -moz-calc(~"100% - 30px");
width: -webkit-calc(~"100% - 30px");
width: calc(~"100% - 30px");
```