# Angular compilation .less is calculating pixels as percentage: 'calc(100% - 26px)' to 'calc(76%)

Tags: angular, less

I have the following css declaration in a .less file:

```
.qb-select-content {
    width: calc(100% - 26px);
    float: left;
}
```

When I compile this code, the `angular-cli` converts the `width: calc(100% - 26px);` to `width: calc(76%)`.

Any one can explate why this is happening and how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17904088/1169798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can escape your declaration (notice the `~` tilde):

```
.qb-select-content {
    width: calc(~100% - 26px);
}
```

the above will output after compilation:

```
.qb-select-content {
    width: calc(100% - 26px);
}
```

keep in mind that it's not the angular-cli but your LESS compiler doing this bit

alternatively you can look into interpolation which is a pretty useful feature in other situations too: https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j/wiki/Less-Language-String-Interpolation