# Less CSS3 calc function becomes invalid

Tags: css, less

I have following code in my LESS file,

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
```

In my Localhost environment, it works fine and becomes as below in the generated CSS file.

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
```

However in my Dev-server end. It becomes as below(-becomes ties to the value) hence that makes the expression invalid in the browser.

```
margin-left: calc(50%- 50vw);
margin-right: calc(50%- 50vw);
```

**I tried many ways to overcome this problem by sending this as a String or Mathematical expression to no use.
Some of the things I tried are below**

```
margin-left: calc(~"50% - 50vw");//not working
margin-left: calc(~'50% - 50vw');//not working
margin-left: ~'calc(50% - 50vw)';//not working

margin-left: e('calc(50% - 50vw)');//not working
margin-left: calc(percentage(0.5)if((2 > 1),-, 0)if((2 > 1),50vw, 0));//not working
```

I tried so many numbers of ways all resulted in an invalid expression at the server (localhost works) Any Ideas on how to fix this issue?

Comment: What are you using to compile your LESS? Why don't you compile locally and then send the SCSS/CSS to your dev environment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc

Comment: how do we check the version and compiler in the vs?

Comment: @Seven i think he has indicated those solutions don't work, see below what he has tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the "MVC Bundling", This appears fixed in newer versions of MVC. Updated 4 to 5.2.7 However for older versions,

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
```

You should rewrite it as:

```
margin-left: calc((-50vw) - -50%);
margin-right: calc((-50vw) - -50%);
```

Answer (score 2):

In LESS, you have to escape `calc` this way: `margin-left: ~'calc(50% - 50vw)';`. This works, I've used it many times. If that doesn't work, the problem must be something else.