# Less.js: error evaluating function `min`: incompatible types

Tags: css, gruntjs, less

I have the following styling in my `_main.less` file

```css
#mapid {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: min(65vh, 500px);
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

But the Less compiler complains (using grunt)

```
>> File "public/less/_main.less" changed.
Running "less:development" (less) task
>> ./public/less/_main.less: [L86:C14] error evaluating function `min`: incompatible types
Warning: Error compiling ./public/less/_main.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

But this works fine in CSS ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Refer to [Disable LESS-CSS Overwriting calc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904088/disable-less-css-overwriting-calc), you can use escape string in LessCSS:

```
#mapid {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: ~"min(65vh, 500px)";
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: It works for me for `calc()` calls, but not for `min()` - still getting `ActionView::Template::Error: Incompatible units: '%' and 'px'.`

Comment: @SzymonPrzybył, did you check this? https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2815#issuecomment-575926329

Comment: @Trung0246, `calc(max(1vw, 2px))` doesn’t work for me.  Note that your link refers to Sass, but the question refers to Less.

Comment: Brilliant! this did the trick for me!